# Test Class for Case Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I have a trigger that I got off a comment in the Success Community (thanks Subramani!) that adds Case Comments to Cases during the same import (rather than first importing Cases and then Case Comments based on the parent ID). The trigger is in the Sandbox and I am unable to deploy it because there is not enough code covereage. I am told that I need to have a test class for this trigger in order to be able to test and deploy it to Production. I am pretty new to SF administration and have almost no experience writing in Apex. Would anyone be able to help me create a test class for the following trigger?

```
trigger CreateCaseComment on Case (after insert) {

List<CaseComment > casecmlist=new list<CaseComment >();

for(Case c : Trigger.new){
     if(c.commentCL__c!= ''){

        CaseComment cc = new CaseComment();
        cc.commentBody = c.commentCL__c;
        cc.ParentId = c.Id;
        casecmlist.add(cc);
     }
 }
 if(casecmlist!=null){
 insert casecmlist;
 }
}
```

I really appreciate any assistance I can get! Thank you!

Comment: Good time to learn. Head over to trailhead. We can help you when you get stuck. SFSE is not a service to get free dev. We will be here to help you learn as you have specific questions though ;)

Comment: HI Claire, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to take the [tour], visit the [help], and read [ask]. When you write a post, you should strive to demonstrate what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. As written currently, this post just reads more like a request to have someone do your work for you. As mentioned already, **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_triggers)** is a great place to go if you're not sure where to start. SFSE is more for when you get hung up on a specific issue and has more of a learning curve.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I have been making my way though Trailhead, but have been mainly focused on Admin trails. I'll make sure to dig in deeper to the Dev ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) to write your first test class.

1) Create a test method

2) In the method, create a list of cases.

```
List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
for(integer i=0;i<5, i++)
{
    //put all the mandatory fields to create a case.
    Case caseObj = new Case(Subject='Test', Status = 'New', commentCL__c = 'test' + i);
    lstCase.add(caseObj);
}
insert lstCase;
```

3) After insertion, put proper assert statement to validate your result.